# C programming to calculate using modular exponentiation

Tags: c, recursion, modulo, exponentiation

I just had a quick question to verify if my programming and math are correct. Sorry in advance if this is off topic, I don't where else to ask to get quality answers ;) How can I double check that the answer is correct? Thanks

This is my problem:

If a cryptosystem has 2^48 possible keys, and you have 1000 computers, each of which can test 500,000 encryption keys per second, in how many days would you be able to recover the correct key in the worst case, assuming a brute force search and that you can immediately recognize the correct key when you have tried decrypting with it? (Recall, there are 86,400 seconds in a day.)

Here is my program output to solve the problem:

```
Number of keys: 2^48
Number of computers: 1000
Number of keys/persecond: 500000
Number of days: 647168000
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int max_power(int base,int exp,int mod);
int main(void)
{
    int num_computers=1000;
    int keys_per_second= 500000;
    int seconds_in_day=86400;
    printf("Number of keys: 2^48\n");
    printf("Number of computers: %d\n",num_computers);
    printf("Number of keys/persecond: %d\n",keys_per_second);
    printf("Number of days: %d\n",max_power(2,48,seconds_in_day)*num_computers*keys_per_second);

    return 0;
}

int max_power(int base,int exp,int mod)
{
    if (exp == 0)
        return 1;
else if (exp%2 == 0) {
        int mysqrt = max_power(base, exp/2, mod);
        return (mysqrt*mysqrt)%mod;
    }
    else
        return (base*max_power(base, exp-1, mod))%mod;
}
```

Final code (still not completely satisfied but I will ask my professor if this would be acceptable on a test):

```
int main(void)
{
    double num_computers=1000;
    double keys_per_second= 500000;
    double seconds_in_day=86400;
    long double keys=pow(2.0,48);
    printf("Number of keys: %.0lf\n",keys);
    printf("Number of computers: %.0f\n",num_computers);
    printf("Number of keys/persecond: %.0f\n",keys_per_second);
    printf("============================================\n");
    printf("Time to decrypt all keys: %.2f days\n",keys/(num_computers*keys_per_second*seconds_in_day));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't looked at what your code is doing, but, how about wolfram alpha? [(2^48)/(500000*1000*86400) = 6.5156... days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%282%5E48%29%2F%28500000*1000*86400%29). Hope I understood what your question was.

Comment: This gets a whole lot simpler if you use 64-bit integers,btw.

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you did there and how is it not (2^48)/(500000*1000*86400) ~ 6.5156? Or 1000 times that if you interpret "worse case" as all the computers testing exactly the same keys on the same order till all of them get to the answer at the same time?

Comment: I agree with @Macattack & brunocodutra.  Except I just used a regular desktop calculator, came up with identical results.  Did you ever put seconds/day in the denominator?  You may be using the modulus operator incorrectly

Comment: Just curious, why did someone mark this down?  Other than a miscalculation (which he is asking about) I don't know what's wrong with the question.

Comment: Pretty sure I'm using mod wrong. I changed the arithmetic to:
printf("Number of days: %f\n",(2.81474977*pow(10.0,14))/(num_computers*keys_per_second*seconds_in_day)); to get the correct answer, so thanks for that.

But I'm not too comfortable with that answer because I wont always have a powerful enough calculator or wolfram at my disposal. I may have to reproduce code similar to this by hand on a test and my misuse/misunderstanding of mod is going to cause my answer to be wrong. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The correct calculation was pointed out in the comments. However, you are still not sure how you went wrong.

Your application of [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) here is not quite correct. Modular exponentiation only gives you the **remainder** of x to the y over z, you also need the **quotient**.